# mySQL - How to convert a string to an int and string to date using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, string, date, integer

so I have this table that stores the quantity and created_on(date) field as a string, I want to convert the quantity field to int and the created_on field to date, because I want to manipulate the data in PowerBI, therefore I want to create view that converts the fields to manage the data correctly. This is my current query that gets the four fields I need for my view

```
SELECT total_qty, delivery_agent_name, created_on, shipment_stage
FROM  express_shipment
```

And this is the output, which would be the same once the conversion is done, I just need the conversion for PowerBI purposes.
[image]
Thank you again!

Comment: Use the `CAST()` function.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I've never used the ```CAST()``` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a string to a number by adding `0` to it.

You can convert a string to a DATETIME using `CAST()`

```
SELECT 0 + total_qty AS total_qty, delivery_agent_name, CAST(created_on AS DATETIME) AS created_on, shipment_stage
FROM sompopo_dwh_express.sompopo_express_shipment
```

Comment: you can also do `timestamp(created_on)`  or `cast(total_qty as int)` for that matter

Comment: @ysth See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) for the allowed types. You can use `AS SIGNED`, but not `AS INT`

Comment: @Barmar ah, just mariadb allows that.